# can't download wordpress posts using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

hello i have a list of posts and i use javascript to `download a post as pdf`
but i have a problem because the download button works just on the first post and not in the others and when i inspect the button in the browser i can see the description below but the button not working

this is a part of my code if some one could help :

ps: the download button is : Imprimer l'offre

```html
<li style=" border: 1px solid black; padding: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px;" <?php job_listing_class(); ?> data-longitude="<?php echo esc_attr($post->geolocation_long); ?>" data-latitude="<?php echo esc_attr($post->geolocation_lat); ?>">
  <!--  <a href="<?php the_job_permalink(); ?>">
     -->
  <!-- <?php the_company_logo(); ?> -->
  <div class="work-section">
    <h3><?php wpjm_the_job_title(); ?> <?php echo "Job ID: " . $post->ID ?> </h3>
    <!-- <div class="company">
                    <?php the_company_name('<strong>', '</strong> '); ?>
                    <?php the_company_tagline('<span class="tagline">', '</span>'); ?>
                </div> -->
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="location">
                <?php the_job_location(false); ?>
            </div> -->
  <div id="tblCustomers">
    <div id="collapseExample<?php echo  $post->ID ?>" class=" collapse job_description">
      <?php wpjm_the_job_description(); ?>
    </div>
    <div id="print-btn"></div>

  </div>

  <center>
    <div class="vc_btn3-container  red-btn vc_btn3-inline" style="margin-top: 20px">
      <button id="pdfview" data-target="<?php echo  $post->ID ?>" style="text-align: center;">
        Imprimer l’offre
      </button>

      <div id="pdfdiv" style="display: none;">
        <?php wpjm_the_job_description(); ?>
      </div>

      <div id="editor"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

        $(window).on('load', function() {
          var doc = new jsPDF();
          var specialElementHandlers = {
            '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
              return true;
            }
          };
          $('#pdfview').click(function() {
            doc.fromHTML($('#pdfdiv').html(), 15, 15, {
              'width': 700,
              'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.save('file.pdf');
          });
        });
      </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. Without seeing all of your code, it appears you are assigning the `pdfview` ID to every button in your list of posts. This isn't going to work - use classes instead.

Comment: The `ID` attribute cannot have any duplicates. I'm assuming your problem is that you use the same `ID` for every button. To get around this, make `pdfdiv` a _class_ instead of an ID, and then in jQuery you can select it with `$(".pdfdiv")` and it should work.

Comment: I think you need to provide more information about the context of your code and usage. When you refer to the pdf only working for the first post, do you mean first post in terms of the post_id ? or that you are trying to generate multiple posts as pdf but it only works for the first selected one? From what I see, your pdf context comes from #pdfdiv which is only loaded once through your php code and this is likely to be intentional since it looks like a post template page?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i have tried to use it as class but still have the same problem

Comment: @Niraeth i have a list of posts undre every post i have a download button to generate a pdf that includ the discription of the post

Comment: Ok so your feature is meant to download multiple posts as pdf right? If so then you will need to change how your code works. You will have to use javascript to loop through the post data. As it is now, it only works for one post because the code is meant to work for one post. Will be helpful if you can show the code for the 'list of posts' as well, to see how you are loading them.

Comment: no just a single pdf pear button  @Niraeth

Comment: Ok but either way you will need to make modifications to your js code so that your #pdfview on click pulls data from a variable that contains the post data, instead of it pulling data from the current static #pdfdiv. Without the full code, I can't really assist you.

Comment: thank you guys its working now, i have just to add the ID to the script